# too many concurrent cURL connections block transfer completely

Tags: php, curl

I am using cURL in PHP to transfer as many files as possible through concurrent connections.

Therefore I have build a curl multi handle which takes care of catching all the files and sending them.

I have also used some options to set the maximum number of concurrent connections like this:

```
# activate additional options for the multi cURL call
curl_multi_setopt($mh, CURLMOPT_PIPELINING, 3);
curl_multi_setopt($mh, CURLMOPT_MAX_HOST_CONNECTIONS, $max_curl_cons);
curl_multi_setopt($mh, CURLMOPT_MAX_TOTAL_CONNECTIONS, $max_curl_cons);
```

When I use a value like 10 for my `$max_curl_cons` the script runs fine and transfers its file until its told to stop (measuring the time for a trip through the curl multi handle and checking that against max execution time).

Now when I want to speed up the transfers I would love to build up more concurrent connections. So I raised `$max_curl_cons` to 50 for example. Instead of making it, at least slightly faster, this completely blocks any transfers and my script stops without having a single file transferred.

On the server this script is running on and on the other side we have opened 1.000 ports to allow free flow of bytes. ;-)

Nevertheless we do not manage to speed this up, 20 connections is basically the same speed as 10 and with any more it just stops transferring at all without any error messages and alike.

How can I debug this further?

Comment: Have you raised error reporting levels and checked your logs? cURL can be _very_ resource hungry - you might simply be running out of memory.

Comment: I will check this and come back to you.

Comment: What if the remote server does not allow more than 20 simultaneous connections from one IP? Sometimes it is done to prevent DOS attacks. Your curl script could be receiving a sensible error message explaining the reason.

Comment: Hey @Salman A, we have checked this with the other host. He has opened up everything and he could and whitelisted our IP. So we should be good to go there. And PHP is not throwing any errors at all. Still waiting for log access but there is no visible feedback from our server.

Comment: @flomei just to be sure, look at the server response and note down the error codes. I recently setup a webserver to deny more than 5 connections per IP to stop a rogue scraper script.

Comment: since the speed is roughly the same between 10 and 20 connections, i think you're hitting a bandwidth limit somewhere, and more connections won't do you any good anyway. but i'd start by writing a little server that only accepts connections and ignores everything received, then writing a little client that opens a new connection every second, and keeps all connections open, and send a byte or 2 on all open connections, which should show you how many connections you can have open before it gets unstable